# put image on another image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and I need to set an image on another one. Here are my images:

```
<div class="span6" style="text-align: center">
    <img alt="" src="img/media/tv/originals.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <img alt="" src="img/media/tv/arrow.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <img alt="" src="img/media/tv/constantine.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <img alt="" src="img/media/tv/house-of-cards.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <img alt="" src="img/media/tv/originals.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
```

There is one image (for example 1.png) that I need to be on all these images (like watermark) and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please create an example of what you tried so far with f. e. http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: try using a `css` background image.

Comment: here is an example question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747520/using-svg-or-css-to-add-a-watermark-or-overlay-to-an-image-on-a-web-page

Answer (score -1):

this post was helpful !
[using SVG or CSS to add a "watermark" or overlay to an image on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747520/using-svg-or-css-to-add-a-watermark-or-overlay-to-an-image-on-a-web-page)

HTML Code:

```
<div class='imageholder'>
    <img src='img/1.png' alt=''>
    <div class='watermark'>WATERMARK</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.imageholder{position:relative;}
.watermark
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

well, i didn't need that bg color CSS, so removed it. if you don't have a text as watermark, it's better to remove it !

Comment: Since @Sebsemillia  answered your question you should upvote their answer rather than pasting the linked content.